# How to calculate an formula in a different timeframe

Tags: pine-script

Suppose I have this code to calculate SMIsignal , emasignal .

```
//@version=4
study("test", overlay=true)

    a = 20
    b = 2
    ob = 40
    os = -40
    // Range Calculation
    ll = lowest (low, a)
    hh = highest (high, a)
    diff = hh - ll
    rdiff = close - (hh+ll)/2
    avgrel = ema(ema(rdiff,b),b)
    avgdiff = ema(ema(diff,b),b)
    SMI = avgdiff != 0 ? (avgrel/(avgdiff/2)*100) : 0

    ////////////////////////////////////////
    SMIsignal = ema(SMI,b)
    emasignal = ema(SMI, 10)
```

Trading view will calculate the value for the timeframe used in Tradingview e.g. 20 minutes .
What code should I use if I would calculate SMIsignal and emasignal  for a different timeframe for example 7 minutes ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `security` function

example:

```
// both in same timeframe but the chart in different timeframe 
[_smi, _ema] =security(syminfo.tickerid, "7", [SMIsignal, emasignal])
```

or

```
// 7-min resolution
_smi = security(syminfo.tickerid, "7", SMIsignal)
// 20-min resolution
_ema = security(syminfo.tickerid, "20", emasignal)
```

for more information check https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/#fun_security